# async await with nodejs 7

Tags: node.js, async-await

I've installed nodejs 7.3.0 and I have this code:

```js
let getContent = function (url) {
    // return new pending promise
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // select http or https module, depending on reqested url
        const lib = url.startsWith('https') ? require('https') : require('http');
        const request = lib.get(url, (response) => {
            // handle http errors
            if (response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode > 299) {
                reject(new Error('Failed to load page, status code: ' + response.statusCode));
            }
            // temporary data holder
            const body = [];
            // on every content chunk, push it to the data array
            response.on('data', (chunk) => body.push(chunk));
            // we are done, resolve promise with those joined chunks
            response.on('end', () => resolve(body.join('')));
        });
        // handle connection errors of the request
        request.on('error', (err) => reject(err))
    })
};

let get = async function (url) {
    var content = await getContent(url);
    return content;
}

var html = get('https://developer.mozilla.org/it/');
```

In debug I receive this:

```
let get = async function (url) {
                ^^^^^^^^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
        at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:78:16)
        at Module._compile (module.js:543:28)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
```

Comment: Are you sure it's supported without any flags? From what I can see [here](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/), it looks like you need to spawn your node with either `--harmony` or `--es_staging` flag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Node 7.3.0 does not support async/await without a feature flag](http://node.green/). Spawning node like this should do the trick:

```
node --harmony-async-await app.js
```

**EDIT**

Node now officially supports [async/await by default in version 7.6.0](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v7.6.0/#notable-changes), which comes from updating V8, Chromium’s JavaScript engine, to [version 5.5](https://v8project.blogspot.com.es/2016/10/v8-release-55.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know about flag option.

Comment: @asv warning: not recommended in production!

Comment: Thano you to everyone. For production maybe we must wait for Node 8.0.0