# How to debug code after await in Typescript in Vscode?

Tags: node.js, typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code, async-await

I am on Vscode 1.33.1, Node 11.12, Typescript 3.4.3, vscode-chrome-debug-core 6.7.46 and I'm trying to debug a React Native project.

As long as I don't hit `await`, everything works perfectly. However, when I hit a line that contains `await`, I don't hit any breakpoint after the `await` line (including the `await` line). The code runs normally, but debugger gets messed up. If I put a breakpoint just before the `await` line and try to step in/over/out, it jumps into the ugly `index.bundle` code.

This happens at multiple locations in my app, so it's not an isolated case to one point either.

Here is my active configuration in `launch.json`:

```
{
    "name": "Debug iOS (sim)",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
    "type": "reactnative",
    "request": "launch",
    "platform": "ios",
    "sourceMaps": true,
    "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react",
    "smartStep": true,
    "skipFiles": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**/*.js",
        "${workspaceFolder}/lib/**/*.js",
        "<node_internals>/**/*.js"
      ]
},
```

As seen from the configuration, I've already tried `smartStep` (which. Vscode about that being not allowed anyway), `skipFiles` (it really does skip files unless I explicitly step in so it works, but doesn't solve the problem). I've also seen [Debug Node.js Async/Await with Typescript+VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41644827/debug-node-js-7-async-await-with-typescriptvscode) but I've already tried `smartStep` and the concerns of that question are old and are already solved many releases ago.

How can I debug Typescript code that contains `await` properly?

**UPDATE**: When I bypass Vscode debuggings/configurations and debug in Chrome and vanilla terminal (i.e. `react-native run-ios`) it works perfectly. So it's something with Vscode or its configuration.

**UPDATE 2**: I'm targeting ES2017, and here's my `tsconfig`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
     "moduleResolution": "node",
     "baseUrl": "./app",
     "paths": {
       "assets/*": ["assets/*"],
       "components/*": ["components/*"],
       "navigation/*": ["navigation/*"],
       "utils/*": ["utils/*"],
       "views/*": ["views/*"],
       "types/*": ["types/*"],
       "services/*": ["services/*"],
       "state/*": ["state/*"],
       "constants/*": ["constants/*"]
     },
     "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

Comment: What version of javascript are you targeting? I've personally had issues with debugging when compiling Typescript down to pre-es6 javascript where async/await is compiled into generator functions.

Comment: @JakeHolzinger I'm targeting ES2017.

Comment: How does the generated JavaScript code look around the 'await'?

Comment: @MichaelDreher lots of `switch`es and `case`s jumping wildly around each other.

Comment: Do you actually have async and await keywords in the generated javascript? I second @JakeHolzinger's experience where VSCode's debugger messes up like this if the generated JS does not contain async and await keywords, but works fine if it does. Strange that you're getting it with an ES2017 target.

Comment: @user240515 Nope, generated JS doesn't have await/async, they get translated to ugly nested promises by Babel. Maybe React Native doesn't that syntax, but I'll have a look into that.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu Did you ever get this solved?

Answer (score 2):

For debugging I would recommend you to use [`ndb`](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/ndb) (Node Debugger) from Google. It uses the dev tools from Google Chrome on your Node project.

When you have ndb installed correctly you can simply run your files via: `ndb node index.js` etc.

It will automatically start the debugger and run your command:

[image: Screenshot]
Image source: https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/ndb/blob/v1.1.4/README.md

I for myself think that this is much better than the VSCode debugger.

As you want to run TypeScript files you should probably add `ts-node` as an devDependency in your `package.json` which will allow you to run TypeScript files without compiling.

You can use `ndb` like this then: `ndb ts-node index.ts`

---

Still, TypeScript is not perfectly supported in any debugger atm. If you need full debugging functionallity, you should probably debug the compiled JavaScript version - you could pretty-up your `tsconfig.json` to make the code somewhat readable

Comment: What exactly is better in `ndb` compared to Vscode's debugger, which is also based on Chrome debugger?