# Using async/await in node 7.4

Tags: node.js, async-await

I thought async/await was supported in node 7.4, however this example does not work:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');

async function main(){
  await Promise.delay(1000)
}

main();
```

Results in:

```
async function main(){
      ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
```

How can I use async/await with node 7.4?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [async await with nodejs 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41347260/async-await-with-nodejs-7)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Yes async-await is supported in Node.js v7 but its locked behind the `harmony` flag. Features which are not yet production ready are behind this flag.

To use async-await in Node.js v7 simply run Node service with this flag -

`node --harmony-async-await app.js`

The official release of async-await is slated for Node.js v8 which will be launched in April.

You can follow [this](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/9618) pull request to check its status. Basically the correct functioning of async-await is dependent on the integration of V8 engine v5.5 into Node.js. Currently Node.js uses V8 v5.4 which is solved by this pull request.

**Update 1** - It seems V8 v5.5 might be coming to Node.js v7. Follow [this](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/11062) pull request for more details.

**Update 2** - Good news guys! Node.js version 7.6.0 now officially supports `async` functions without using the `--harmony` flag as V8 engine 5.5 has been successfully ported.

Now you only need  to use the `--harmony` flag if your Node.js version is between 7.0 to 7.5.0 (inclusive). For complete changelog refer [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V7.md#7.6.0).

Answer (score 14):

Node.js 7.6.0 released several hours ago and they included v8 5.5.
Now you can use async/await without flag.

Answer (score 2):

You will need harmony flag for this to work.

Try again with `node --harmony-async-await myscript.js`

Answer (score 2):

Node version 7.6 now supports async/await out of the box. If you haven’t tried it yet,  you should adopt it immediately and never look back.

```
  const makeRequest = () =>
      getJSON()
        .then(data => {
          console.log(data)
          return "done"
        })

    makeRequest()
```

And using async/await:

```
const makeRequest = async () => {
  console.log(await getJSON())
  return "done"
}

makeRequest()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, what I did is installed asyncawait using below command

```
npm install asyncawait
```

afterwards i declared await and async using below command

```
const async = require('asyncawait/async');
const await = require('asyncawait/await');
```

then used these where it was required but my commands were within `async(my-code) & await(my-code)`.

And it worked perfectly for me.

Comment: hi and welcome to stackockflow, for an answer please provide more information like why your solution works and what was done wrong. Those answers can be found an google etc. and should be clear for everyone. Thanks for contributing and good luck!

Comment: Welcome to SO. As mischva11 mentioned, please explain your answer in details. In addition, please follow the SO guidelines while giving an answer. You can read the same here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer