# Achieve error differentiation in Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, promise

### Background

I have a REST API using MongoDB, Node.js and Express that makes a request to my NoSQL DB and depending on different results, I want to differentiate which error I send the customer.

### Problem

The current version of my code has a generic error handler and always sends the same error message to the client:

```
api.post("/Surveys/", (req, res) => {
        const surveyJSON = req.body;
        const sender = replyFactory(res);

        Survey.findOne({_id: surveyJSON.id})
            .then(doc => {
                if(doc !== null)
                    throw {reason: "ObjectRepeated"};

                //do stuff
                return new Survey(surveyJSON).save();
            })
            .then(() => sender.replySuccess("Object saved with success!")) 
            .catch(error => {
                /*
                 * Here I don't know if:
                 * 1. The object is repeated
                 * 2. There was an error while saving (eg. validation failed)
                 * 3. Server had a hiccup (500)
                 */
                sender.replyBadRequest(error);    
            });
    });
```

This is a problem, because the client will always get the same error message, no matter what and I need error differentiation!

### Research

I found a possible solution, based on the division of logic and error/response handling:

- [Handling multiple catches in promise chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26076511/handling-multiple-catches-in-promise-chain)

However, I don't understand a few things:

1. I don't see how, at least in my example, I can separate the logic from the response. The response **will depend** on the logic after all!
2. I would like to avoid error sub-classing and hierarchy. First because I don't use bluebird, and I can't subclass the error class the answer suggests, and second because I don't want my code with a billion different error classes with brittle hierarchies that will change in the future.

### My idea, that I don't really like either

With this structure, if I want error differentiation, the only thing I can do is to detect an error occurred, build an object with that information and then throw it:

```
.then(doc => {
    if(doc === null)
        throw {reason: "ObjectNotFound"};

    //do stuff
    return doc.save();
})
.catch(error => {
    if(error.reason === "ObjectNotFound")  
        sendJsonResponse(res, 404, err);
    else if(error.reason === "Something else ")
        sendJsonResponse(/*you get the idea*/);
    else //if we don't know the reasons, its because the server likely crashed
        sendJsonResponse(res, 500, err);
});
```

I personally don't find this solution particularly attractive because it means I will have a huge `if then else` chain of statements in my `catch` block.

Also, as mentioned in the previous post, generic error handlers are usually frowned upon (and for a good reason imo).

### Questions

How can I improve this code?

Comment: _"How can I improve this code?"_ What would be considered an improvement? There is no issue if `if..else if` statements return expected result. Perhaps ask Question at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: It looks like you *do* get different error messages already?

Comment: "*I will have a huge if then else chain of statements*" - why, are your `sendJsonResponse` calls that different for all the possible cases?

Comment: Don't use a brittle hierarchy of error subclasses, just use duck typing.

Comment: @Bergi: I have different errors already but I am not taking advantage of it. Instead I have a generic error handler which is bound to become a nightmare in the future.

Comment: Use a format for your different errors that makes the generic error handler  simple - e.g. give them all `httpStatus` and `userMessage` properties.

Comment: @Bergi: I also thought about that. But what happens if I get a genuine server error, one that I didn't built? Pretty much I would have check if the error in my generic catch has the X, Y and Z properties, and if not build an object with that information. I suppose it is better than a huge `if then else`...

Comment: No, if you get an error without the properties you need in the generic handler you'll want to log it and throw a generic "500 internal server error". Wrapping foreign errors should happen at the point where they are thrown, not in a generic matcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Objectives

When I started this thread, I had two objectives in mind:

1. Having error differentiation
2. Avoid an `if then else` of doom in a generic catcher

I have now come up with two radically distinct solutions, which I now post here, for future reference.

### Solution 1: Generic error handler with Errors Object

This solution is based on the solution from [@Marc Rohloff](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/130137/marc-rohloff), however, instead of having an array of functions and looping through each one, I have an object with all the errors.

This approach is better because it is faster, and removes the need for the `if` validation, meaning you actually do less logic:

```
const errorHandlers = {
    ObjectRepeated: function(error){
        return { code: 400, error };
    },
    SomethingElse: function(error){
        return { code: 499, error };
    }
};

Survey.findOne({
        _id: "bananasId"
    })
    .then(doc => {

        //we dont want to add this object if we already have it
        if (doc !== null)
            throw { reason: "ObjectRepeated", error:"Object could not be inserted because it already exists."};

        //saving empty object for demonstration purposes
        return new Survey({}).save();
    })
    .then(() => console.log("Object saved with success!"))
    .catch(error => {
        respondToError(error);
    });

    const respondToError = error => {
        const errorObj = errorHandlers[error.reason](error);

        if (errorObj !== undefined)
            console.log(`Failed with ${errorObj.code} and reason ${error.reason}: ${JSON.stringify(errorObj)}`);
        else 
            //send default error Obj, server 500
            console.log(`Generic fail message ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
    };
```

This solution achieves:

1. Partial error differentiation (I will explain why)
2. Avoids an `if then else` of doom.

This solution only has partial error differentiation. The reason for this is because you can only differentiate errors that you specifically build, via the `throw {reaon: "reasonHere", error: "errorHere"}` mechanism.

In this example, you would be able to know if the document already exists, but if there is an error saving the said document (lets say, a validation one) then it would be treated as "Generic" error and thrown as a 500.

To achieve full error differentiation with this, you would have to use the  [nested Promise anti pattern](http://www.datchley.name/promise-patterns-anti-patterns/) like the following:

```
.then(doc => {

    //we dont want to add this object if we already have it
    if (doc !== null)
        throw { reason: "ObjectRepeated", error:"Object could not be inserted because it already exists." };

    //saving empty object for demonstration purposes
    return new Survey({}).save()
        .then(() => {console.log("great success!");})
        .catch(error => {throw {reason: "SomethingElse", error}});
})
```

It would work... But I see it as a best practice to avoid anti-patterns.

### Solution 2: Using ECMA6 Generators via `co`.

This solution uses [Generators](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ategZqxHkz4) via the library [`co`](https://github.com/tj/co). Meant to replace Promises in near future with a syntax similar to `async/await` this new feature allows you to write asynchronous code that reads like synchronous (well, almost).

To use it, you first need to install `co`, or something similar like [ogen](https://github.com/ericelliott/ogen). I pretty much prefer co, so that is what i will be using here instead.

```
const requestHandler = function*() {

    const survey = yield Survey.findOne({
        _id: "bananasId"
    });

    if (survey !== null) {
        console.log("use HTTP PUT instead!");
        return;
    }

    try {
        //saving empty object for demonstration purposes
        yield(new Survey({}).save());
        console.log("Saved Successfully !");
        return;
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(`Failed to save with error:  ${error}`);
        return;
    }

};

co(requestHandler)
    .then(() => {
        console.log("finished!");
    })
    .catch(console.log);
```

The generator function `requestHandler` will `yield` all Promises to the library, which will resolve them and either return or throw accordingly.

Using this strategy, you effectively code like you were coding synchronous code (except for the use of `yield`).

I personally prefer this strategy because:

1. Your code is easy to read and it looks synchronous (while still have the advantages of asynchronous code).
2. You **do not** have to build and throw error objects every where, you can simply send the message immediately.
3. And, you can *BREAK* the code flow via `return`. This is not possible in a promise chain, as in those you have to force a `throw` (many times a meaningless one) and catch it to stop executing.

The generator function will only be executed once passed into the library `co`, which then returns a Promise, stating if the execution was successful or not.

This solution achieves:

1. error differentiation
2. avoids `if then else` hell and generalized catchers (although you will use `try/catch` in your code, and you still have access to a generalized catcher if you need one).

Using generators is, in my opinion, more flexible and makes for easier to read code. Not all cases are cases for generator usage (like mpj suggests in the video) but in this specific case, I believe it to be the best option.

### Conclusion

**Solution 1**: good classical approach to the problem, but has issues inherent to promise chaining. You can overcome some of them by nesting promises, but that is an anti pattern and defeats their purpose.

**Solution 2**: more versatile, but requires a library and knowledge on how generators work. Furthermore, different libraries will have different behaviors, so you should be aware of that.

Comment: This is a good answer, but 1) nested promises are not an antipattern where necessary for control flow (at least as long as you `return` them monadically) 2) `async`/`await` is already here (in spec, native implementations and transpilers), there is no reason to use co any more

Comment: Hello, but 1) nested promises are considered an anti pattern (check the article I link to) and 2) I use Node.js, and the async/await feature is not completely flushed out (only available in harmony mode, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41756622/using-async-await-in-node-7-4), so yes, there is a case for `co`, until at least the feature is flushed out. Other than that I agree that once the feature is completely flushed, there won't be a need for `co`!

Comment: It appears that Node.js > 7.6 fully supports `asyn/await` ! You were right, I think I have some catching up to do ! PS: there is no need for `co` after all!

Answer (score 0):

I think a good improvement would be creating an error utility method that takes the error message as a parameter, then does all your ifs to try to parse the error (logic that does have to happen somewhere) and returns a formatted error.

```
function errorFormatter(errMsg) {
   var formattedErr = {
    responseCode: 500,
    msg: 'Internal Server Error'
};

  switch (true) {
     case errMsg.includes('ObjectNotFound'):
      formattedErr.responseCode = 404;
      formattedErr.msg = 'Resource not found';
      break;
  }
  return formattedErr;
}
```

Comment: I also thought about this, unfortunately, this will only move the `if then else` nightmare to somewhere else. I want to avoid it completely.