# Syntax Error: Unexpected Token async()

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have been following [this](https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-js/4-connectors/) tutorial on using GraphQL and it has told me to write this block of code in my `src/index.js` file:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const {graphqlExpress, graphiqlExpress} = require('apollo-server-express');
const schema = require('./schema');

// 1
const connectMongo = require('./mongo-connector');

// 2
const start = async () => {
  // 3
  const mongo = await connectMongo();
  var app = express();
  app.use('/graphql', bodyParser.json(), graphqlExpress({
    context: {mongo}, // 4
    schema
  }));
  app.use('/graphiql', graphiqlExpress({
    endpointURL: '/graphql',
  }));

  const PORT = 3000;
  app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Hackernews GraphQL server running on port ${PORT}.`)
  });
};

// 5
start();
```

Though when I try to run the code using: `node ./src/index.js` it gives me this error:

```
const start = async () => {
                    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
```

I've searched online and it seems that if might be caused by the node.js version from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41756622/using-async-await-in-node-7-4/41757243#41757243) but I've checked my noed.js version and it's `8.3.0` so it should be supported without having to use Babel if I'm not mistaken.

Here is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "graphql-js-tutorial",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-server-express": "^1.1.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "express": "^4.15.4",
    "graphql": "^0.11.2",
    "graphql-tools": "^1.2.2",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.31"
  }
}
```

Comment: `async` is considered as a function name, and arrow functions don't accept names.

Comment: @Teemu - are you sure?

Comment: which version of nodejs

Comment: @JaromandaX In the context of `async` not recognized as a keyword, yes, I'm sure.

Comment: with `node -v` in command line it says `v6.11.2`

Comment: @Teemu - that code works fine in nodejs 8.4 (available since node 8.3)

Comment: there's your issue ... seeing as you aren't even using `async` correctly if it were supported, just don't use it

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, it does, but OP apparently doesn't use the said version. Only I've said, that the error is fired because of the named arrow function, and that still stands.

Comment: Though when I type `brew upgrade node` it says I can't upgrade as I'm on version `8.3.0`

Comment: well, if you actually were on 8.3 you wouldn't see this problem - I think you probably have multiple versions of node installed

Comment: @Teemu - I do understand now - I did assume from the syntax that the intent was to use (badly) `async` function - which does seem to be the case

Comment: @YellowPillow don't use Homebrew to install Node.js, it gives nothing but grief. Use the official installer.

Comment: Maybe you have multiple node's installed?

Answer (score 5):

[async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) are only available since node 8.3

your code is equivalent to (without async/await)

```
const start = () => {
    return connectMongo().then(mongo => {
        var app = express();
        app.use('/graphql', bodyParser.json(), graphqlExpress({
            context: {mongo}, // 4
            schema
        }));
        app.use('/graphiql', graphiqlExpress({
            endpointURL: '/graphql',
        }));

        const PORT = 3000;
        app.listen(PORT, () => {
            console.log(`Hackernews GraphQL server running on port ${PORT}.`)
        });
        return;
    });
};
```

Comment: This happened to me today when I was trying to run code in Node 6.x that was intended for 8.x where async functions are now fully supported.

Answer (score -1):

start your app by the command `node yourAppFile -harmony`!
`async` function is available in the `harmony` mode under Node7.+

Comment: How does that help the OP - running `6.11.2` (which wont enable async) or if he's running `8.3` like `brew` is telling him, he doesn't need the flag